# Adobe Experience Manager - Hidden content for headless consumption

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

I am conceptualizing a private area for users (React SPA, SSO, microservices, yadda-yadda) that also needs to serve rich static content, that would **non public**.    There is also a public microsite associated with this that will live on top of AEM.  My idea would be to also use the AEM instance deployed for the public area to serve the non-public static content as well, via Adobe Content Services for integration.   This is ideal because this private content is going to need heavy copywriting.

But then, how to avoid this "non-public" content from being also published on the main public website?  I've seen there is this "Resource Mapping" feature.

Could a resource mapping for the private content be mapped to an external URL -that would be living in the SPA/microservices environment external to AEM- and so perform user authorization if needed?

Comment: AEM should have more than one possible solution for this. You can go with closed user groups, resource mapping, ... It really depends on what you exactly need to achive.

Comment: First idea is not using user authentication on the AEM site, so the "resource mapping approach", can a resource be mapped to an external non-AEM managed URL?

Comment: Not sure I got your usecase right - if your content is not in AEM, you would usually add some rules on your webserver. If you have content on AEM, that should not be delivered on a  specific website (or not at all), you would use mapping - which is the case in most installations anyway. For example people tend to have structures like /content/company/branch/language/home and map https://www.company-branch-host/language to the content path. So there would be no way to access content from pages that are  not in this content tree. Does that help?